# GCM push notification coming but with empty message

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

When I submit data through php file it is giving notification to registered phone but there is an empty message only no message content.Mostly tried all tutorial available online but not getting it.Please help.

Server Side Code:php file

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "umane", "pass");
if(!$con){
die('MySQL connection failed');
}

$db = mysql_select_db("dbname");
if(!$db){
die('Database selection failed');
}

$registatoin_ids = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
array_push($registatoin_ids, $row['registration_id']);

}

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$message = array("Notice" => $_POST['message']);
$fields = array(
'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
'data' => $message,
);

$headers = array(
'Authorization: key= MY API KEY',
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Android Code:

```
public class GcmSender {

    public static final String API_KEY = "My API KEY";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 2 || args[0] == null) {
            System.err.println("usage: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"MESSAGE\" [-Pto=\"DEVICE_TOKEN\"]");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Specify a test message to broadcast via GCM. If a device's GCM registration token is\n" +
                    "specified, the message will only be sent to that device. Otherwise, the message \n" +
                    "will be sent to all devices subscribed to the \"global\" topic.");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Example (Broadcast):\n" +
                    "On Windows:   .\\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\"\n" +
                    "On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\"");
            System.err.println("");
            System.err.println("Example (Unicast):\n" +
                    "On Windows:   .\\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\" -Pto=\"<Your_Token>\"\n" +
                    "On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pmsg=\"<Your_Message>\" -Pto=\"<Your_Token>\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            // Prepare JSON containing the GCM message content. What to send and where to send.
            JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
            jData.put("data", args[0].trim());
            // Where to send GCM message.
            if (args.length > 1 && args[1] != null) {
                jGcmData.put("registration_ids", args[1].trim());
            } else {
                jGcmData.put("registration_ids", "/topics/global");
            }
            // What to send in GCM message.
            jGcmData.put("data", jData);

            // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
            URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Send GCM message content.
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());

            // Read GCM response.
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            String resp = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
            System.out.println(resp);
            System.out.println("Check your device/emulator for notification or logcat for " +
                    "confirmation of the receipt of the GCM message.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to send GCM message.");
            System.out.println("Please ensure that API_KEY has been replaced by the server " +
                    "API key, and that the device's registration token is correct (if specified).");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Receiver Code

```
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("data");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("E Protocol")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where u Define Receiver in android  which will receive  GCM Messages ... ??

Comment: you can follow this tut [Link](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)

Comment: @koutuk i have added  code for receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certain that it's retrieving the POST variable in your PHP code?
Try to replace this:

```
$message = array("Notice" => $_POST['message']);
```

with:

```
$message = array("Notice" => "testing");
```

Also in your receiver you are saying

```
String message = data.getString("data");
```

But you defined your data as "Notice" in the php code, so to retrieve the data you must say:

```
String message = data.getString("Notice");
```