# GCM giving blank response After regenerating API KEY

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, cloud

I am using **Google Cloud Messaging** from last one year with **PHP as server side script** and it is working fine on all app until I hasn't sent notification to one of the may application for one month then after that while sending notification to same app I gets blank response like

```
{"status":[],"0":"\n\n
```

so I assumed that google may have deactivated my API key so I regenerated my API key from developer console and replaced regenerated key with old key on server side and at that time it had worked I was able to send message again but after two week again I am getting blank response like given above and this time I was sent notification to same app everyday.

Comment: Try debugging using `Postman` client, also post your `php` code

Answer (score 0):

From this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270108/gcm-push-notification-coming-but-with-empty-message). It suggested to make sure that it's retrieving the POST variable in your PHP code.

> Try to replace this:
>
> ```
> $message = array("Notice" => $_POST['message']);
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> $message = array("Notice" => "testing");
> ```

You can also check on this [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial/) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging) on how to integrate GCM in PHP backend properly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved after importing project into **firebase**.
**Server API Key** is auto generated by google services and after using those keys on server site i am able to send notification.